# Responsive with polymer

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, polymer

In Bootstrap I would write

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class=row>
  <div class="col-md-4">content</div>
  <div class="col-md-4">content</div>
  <div class="col-md-4">content</div>
</div>
```

I try to make the same thing with polymer with flex but I didn't find a way to do this..

How do I use bootstrap inside polymer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/xIARqr?p=preview) is an example that helped me to understand a little more about how flex layout works. I think you have to use something as follows:

```
<div class="horizontal layout">
  <div class="flex-4"><p>flex three</p></div>
  <div class="flex-4"><p>flex</p></div>
  <div class="flex-4"><p>flex two</p></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just to add to this there is an element called `iron-flex-layout` that can be found [here](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-flex-layout) which was created by the Polymer team to use the new CSS flexbox layout. A tutorial can be found [here](https://elements.polymer-project.org/guides/flex-layout).